# Using a transformer to step down 230V to 12V

Tags: transformer

My circuit uses main electricity in parts of the circuit. However my AVR and other components only need 5V. So I'm using a step down transformer to generate 12V. It's then regulated to 5V.

The transformer won't convert it to dc for me will it?

It just steps it down then outputs a certain voltage depending on it's coils. So I would need to convert it to dc myself right?

Comment: Yes, you answered your question correctly for yourself.

Comment: Bear in mind that transformers are rated for a.c. rms and fully loaded. Once you regulate and smooth, you get close to the peak voltage (minus diode drops), and will probably be 10% higher than that for small current loads on a small transformer (less for larger transformers, see the regulation figure).

Comment: Rectify it baby... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier

Comment: Same exact application, somewhat different question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515/how-to-convert-ac-to-dc

Comment: Comments below assume that you are talking about a [transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#/media/File:Transformer.filament.agr.jpg) when you say "transformer."  Some people I know (not EEs) say "transformer" when they really mean "[external power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_adapter)."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are correct. The transformer will only reduce the voltage (and increase the available current), so you need to add additional circuitry to rectify, smooth and regulate your 12\$V_{AC}\$ transformer output to 5\$V_{DC}\$.

This is the type of circuit you should be looking to build:

[image: AC to DC PSU]

1. The transformer reduces the voltage from mains to 12\$V_{AC}\$ (RMS).
2. The Diode Bridge (known as a bridge rectifier) will convert 12\$V_{AC}\$ to 15\$V_{DC}\$. The voltage is \$\sqrt{2}\$ times minus two diode voltage drops higher than the input voltage because the rectifier output is the peak AC voltage, not the RMS AC voltage.
3. The first capacitor will smooth out the ripples that come from the output of the AC to DC bridge rectifier.
4. The [LM7805](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf) regulator will maintain a constant voltage as the load varies. For example if you are switching a light bulb on and off, the current will go up and down, and if you didn't have a regulator then the voltage would drop as the bulb is switched on. The regulator keeps it at the 5\$V_{DC}\$ your microcontroller needs.
5. The final small capacitor filters out any noise or interference on the regulated side of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the schematic BG100. I see you seen Avatar. It was awesome.

Comment: @BG100, sorry but this is a common error. 12V a.c. into a bridge does not product 12V d.c. More like 17V pk (12 * 1.414)

Comment: Sorry I've been forced onto this project. I'm on a steep learning curve here.  So which one of these rectifiers will do the job for me. http://www.maplin.co.uk/bridge-rectifiers-19088

Comment: Also whats PIV and RMS

Comment: @Martin: Absolutely right... I'll edit and correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Ageis: They will probably all be suitable. As I don't know the details of what you're going to be powering with your supply, I would go for something in the middle. I suggest Maplins order code: AQ98G (the maplins web site is very poor for specs, so it's difficult to compare!)

Comment: @Ageis: PIV = Peak Inverse Voltage - your rectifier needs to withstand at least 17v (see Martin's comment above). RMS = Root-Mean-Squared. This is the conventional way of measuring AC. A 12V rms voltage will produce the same power in a resistor as a 12V dc voltage. In stevenvh's answer, both waveforms have 12V rms voltage, but the first has an average over time of zero and the second (rectified) has an average of 10.8V. Both reach 17V at the positive peak.

Comment: @Ageis: RMS means Root Mean Square. It's a bit tricky to understand this if you don't know a lot about AC waveforms. It's basically the average voltage of AC rather than the peak voltage.

Comment: LOL I don't think I make it as a sparky then LOOOL. I'm training under city and guilds 2330 lv2. It's only a microcontroller and an lcd so I wouldn't think it will draw that much current. Do I only need one? In the schematic it looks like i need 4

Comment: @Ageis: Don't look too much into that... I just picked a mid range one from the list which will be more than adequate. You only need one. The 4 diodes are surrounded by a dotted box which represents your component. An alternative would be to buy 4 separate rectifier diodes and make your own bridge, but this is easier.

Answer (score 10):

The transformer is the first part of the power supply, but you need more to get DC.

The varying input voltage of the transformer creates an equally varying magnetic field in the metal core. This magnetic field in turn creates an, again varying, voltage on the output. Both input and output voltage are sine waves. It's called AC (alternating current) because the sign of the output voltage changes continuously, 100 or 120 times per second, depending on the country you live in.
You rectify this AC voltage to get rid of the sign changes; one pin will always be positive with respect to the other one.

[image]

The one thing which remains to be done now is to flatten the curve, get rid of the bumps. This is done by a capacitor. You now have a DC (direct current) voltage which is already usable for a number of situations. This voltage, however, may still show slight variations, which may be unwanted. To get rid of those you follow the capacitor by a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 10):

If you need 12 VDC, it may be simpler to use an off-the-shelf wall wart with a 12 VDC output. Such devices *do* convert to DC for you. A few of them use exactly the circuit BG100 shows, but nowadays many of them use a switching regulator technique that requires *more* parts, but has a lower net cost.

Comment: +1 One should definitely know the principles behind a power supply, but when it comes to building a product (or hobby project) an off the shelf wall wart is the way to go: These things don't cost a fortune, and you get a nice case, cable, connector. Plus: You can be sure to meet all requirements for mains power (distances, isolation, ...)

Comment: .. and it makes product regulatory approval easier, and you don't have to worry about safety yourself.

Answer (score 5):

> The transformer won't convert it to dc
>   for me will it?

Correct!

> AFAIK it just steps it down then
>   outputs a certain voltage depending on
>   it's coils. So I would need to convert
>   it to dc myself right?

Correct again!

Your transformer will convert \$120V_{AC}\$ to \$12V_{AC}\$. So you'll need to regulate it to \$5V_{DC}\$.

Comment: or in this case, 230V to 12V